# How to speed up a simple SQL query in Access

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, inner-join

```
SELECT status_master.*
FROM 100_orders_open 
INNER JOIN status_master 
ON [100_orders_open].OEHISORD_DOC_NO = status_master.OESTATUS_DOC_NO;
```

**status_master** is a local table with 1.1 million rows.

**100_orders_open**  is a query which filters a local table **order_master** containing 107,441 rows to 301 rows.

Query takes 47 seconds on a 8gb ram machine.
I cannot improve hardware.

Is there a way to improve query performance?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few strategies:

1. Explicitly select the fields needed instead of generalized `*`. Returning less columns may improve performance.
2. Turn `100_orders_open` query into a temp table to relive another query process of ACE engine optimizer. Use make-table query (`SELECT * INTO newtable FROM query`). And index temp table.
3. Index any unique field in table especially in `JOIN` statement (i.e., `OESTATUS_DOC_NO` and the query's source table field `OEHISORD_DOC_NO`).
4. Split the large table into another MS Access file and link it to local database to avoid nearing the 2 GB limit and freeing up cache space. Alternatively upsize to server level database (i.e., SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL) if available. Aside, MS Access like SQLite is a file level database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build and combine the other view (query) into your above query. As others stated the columns used in that other query are indexed, and of course OESTATUS_DOC_NO is also indexed.

Since you state the other query only returns 300 rows, then if indexing can be used here, this query likely will execute near instant.

So you have to drop the query on query (or view on view) as you have and attempt to write the query as a whole – not two separate quires.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Access has much of a query optimizer, but I'd think that either:

```
SELECT status_master.*
FROM status_master 
JOIN 100_orders_open 
ON status_master.OESTATUS_DOC_NO = [100_orders_open].OEHISORD_DOC_NO
```

or

```
SELECT * from status_master WHERE status_master.OESTATUS_DOC_NO IN (SELECT [100_orders_open].OEHISORD_DOC_NO  from 100_orders_open)
```

would be faster.

Not sure where you are at with this, but let me add that the index mentioned by someone else below is very important. I kind of assumed that you would already know that, but shouldn't. Also, I'm not familiar at all with Access, but the 100_orders_open view is essentially running a query each time it's opened as well. What is the SQL for this view? Incorporating what's necessary from that SQL into this query will probably be much faster as well.

Comment: You just added a subquery into main query. I would await the OP on this test but usually a `JOIN` is recommended over `IN`. And yes Jet/ACE engine does have a [query optimizer](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html).

Comment: It depends on the query engine. I do a lot of Oracle work and in Oracle the 2nd query is often the fastest form.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Indeed! I forgot to include dependence on the RDMS. Of course it depends on underlying table structures and indices, too. Hence, I awaited the OP. But on average, `JOIN` aids in readability and specific record retrieval (i.e., imagine adding another `WHERE` condition).

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT status_master.*
FROM 100_orders_open INNER JOIN
     status_master 
     ON [100_orders_open].OEHISORD_DOC_NO = status_master.OESTATUS_DOC_NO;
```

You want an index on `status_master(OESTATUS_DOC_NO)`.  This should provide a significant boost to performance.